# Turning off layers in ArcMap via ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcmap

I'm working on a script in ArcMap 10.1 that takes a screenshot and I need to know how to extinguish (turn off) a layer in my table of contents.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000008000000) object has a read/write property, `visible`, that can be used to turn on/off layers.

This is some basic code that should get you started:

```py
#A list of layer names that you want to be turned off.
names = [x,y,z,etc]

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(, mxd, "Layers")[0]
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df)

for layer in layers:
  if layer.name in names:
    layer.visible = False

arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to add something I hope is helpful from my experience.  The above answer works great, though if someone does further analysis with the layer than this example, order of use of the `.visible` property becomes important.

For example, trying to add many "turned off" layers to dataframe as follows:

```
for lyr in layerlist:
     addlayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(os.path.join(basepath, lyr))
     arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(your_dataframe, addlayer, "BOTTOM")
     addlayer.visible = False #Puts the property after the .AddLayer analysis- won't turn off the layer
# Do further analysis
```

Won't turn off the layers as you add them.  But, the following will:

```
for lyr in layerlist:
     addlayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(os.path.join(basepath, lyr))
     addlayer.visible = False # Moves the property before the .AddLayer analysis turns off layer
     arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(your_dataframe, addlayer, "BOTTOM")
# Do further analysis
```