# Only first 10 layers of Geoserver WMS layers of enabled in ArcGIS

Tags: arcmap, geoserver, wms

I can see only first 10 wms layers of Geoserver is enabled while opening with ArcMap. Is there anyway, I can make all layers enabled?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of ArcMap to stop the (unwanted) loading of hundreds of layers. See the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/web-maps-and-services/adding-wms-services.htm), last paragraph: *"ArcGIS automatically turns on the first 10 layers in any WMS service you add to a map or preview in ArcCatalog."*

Nevertheless, you could write a Python script for ArcMap to enabled all the layers - if really necessary. Here's an [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73433/turning-off-layers-in-arcmap-via-arcpy) to a script.

Comment: Thanks for reply Greg; No, my question is not that one,. mine is about the layer not enabled; if you look closed,. only first 10 layers enabled,. rest are disabled..

Comment: Thanks Greg,. Python script for ArcGIS,. or to Geoserver WMS Layer?

Comment: @NannanSatish: great. I edited my answer, you can accept it, if it solved your problem. I also deleted my comments to avoid misunderstandings.